# clicking on vuebootstrap radio group reset the data in form elements

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have use bootstrap-vue for the form elements and everything seems to be ok but when I click on a radio button to change the value, it resets the other form elements data to their default values.

here is the component code:

```
<template>
<b-form @submit.stop.prevent="setConfigItems">
    <div v-for="item in configItems" v-bind:key="item.id" class="form-group">
        <label v-if="item.options.type==='text'" :for="item.key">{{item.name}}</label>
        <input v-if="item.options.type==='text'" type="text" :name="item.key" :id="item.key" :value="item.value"
               class="form-control">
        <b-form-group v-else :label="item.name">
            <b-form-radio-group v-model="item.value" button-variant="outline-danger" buttons>
                <b-form-radio
                    v-for="(value, name) in item.options.options"
                    :key="name"
                    :name="item.key"
                    :value="name">{{value}}
                </b-form-radio>
            </b-form-radio-group>
        </b-form-group>
    </div>
    <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">save data</b-button>
</b-form>
```

```
<script>
    import {FormRadioPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue'
    import {FormPlugin} from 'bootstrap-vue'

    export default {
        name: "Config",
        components: {FormRadioPlugin, FormPlugin},
        data() {
            return {
                configItems: {}
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getConfigItems();
        },
        methods: {
            getConfigItems() {
                axios.get('/api/dashboard/settings/configs')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.configItems = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            },
            setConfigItems() {
                axios.post('/api/dashboard/settings/configs', this.configItems)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        // this.configItems = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

the response data is a json string that contains the information about form elements and it looks like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"website language","key":"DEFAULT_LANGUAGE","value":"fa_IR","options":{"type":"text"}},
    {"id":2,"name":"website title","key":"TITLE_IN_PERSIAN","value":"website title","options":{"type":"text"}},
    {"id":3,"name":"website title in english","key":"TITLE_ENGLISH","value":"Pars Casting","options":{"type":"text"}},
    {"id":4,"name":"website status","key":"WEBSITE_STATUS","value":"active","options":{"type":"radio","options":{"active":"active","inactive":"inactive"}}}]
```

can anybody help me to find out why this happens and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't use the `v-model` to change the `input value`, so you should change the code as below

```
      <input
        v-if="item.options.type==='text'"
        type="text"
        :name="item.key"
        :id="item.key"
        v-model="item.value"
        class="form-control"
      >
```

It works fine in my code box https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-kepler-kyj4m?file=/src/App.vue:223-411

Comment: thank you,I have add the `v-model` attribute to input but it did not fix the problem. but I use `bootstrap-vue` input and now the problem is fixxed,